# The Image is shaking when applying parallax effect using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get an parallax effect using JavaScript.It is working fine but the image shaking when I scroll.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ScollingParallex</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame
 || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
 || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
 || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
 || function(f){setTimeout(f, 1000/60)}

    var ypos,image;
    function parallex() {
        content = document.getElementById('content');
        ypos = window.pageYOffset;
        console.log(ypos * .9);
        console.log("ypos"+ypos)
        content.style.top = ypos * .9+ 'px';
    }
    // window.addEventListener('scroll', parallex);
    window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
        requestAnimationFrame(parallex)
    },false)

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="content">
    <div class="shape_top_page1">
        <div style="width:980px;display:inline-block;background-color:transparent;">
            <img src="img/img_mobile_add_photo.png"  style="width:330px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="shape_top_page2">
        <div style="width:980px;display:inline-block;background-color:transparent;">
            <img src="img/img_mobile_add_photo1.png"  style="width:330px">
        </div>
    </div>
</disv>


</body>
```

css

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color:black;
    color: #fff;
}
#image {
        position: ;
        z-index: -1
}
#content {
    height: 750px;
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top:-10px; */
    background-color:#707070;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;

}

.center{
    text-align: center;
}

.parallax-target{
    width:100%;
    /*background: #707070;*/
    height:700px;
}

.shape_top_page1
{
    background : #FAC912;
    background : rgba(250, 201, 18, 1);
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

.shape_top_page2
{
    background : wheat;
    /*background : rgba(250, 201, 18, 1);*/
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have given a container(content) and an image is present inside it.When I scroll down I am able to see the parallax effect in action.But the problem  I am facing is the image get some shaking effect (trying to position itself I think ) when I scroll.But When I deliberately put my mouse on the scroll Bar and click it and scroll it works fine.But when I do a free scroll on page the problem occurs. I am not using any jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements with ID "content" which is invalid HTML and might cause the shaking. Also one of them has a space left of the equals sign, which is also invalid. Usually browsers only select the first element when doing a `getElementById` but that plus the relative positioning might confuse the rendering engine. It might also be caused by the expensive `getElementById` which you call every frame. Better call it once and save the reference for later use. This is where most ppl start using jQuery's `$(document).ready()` so that you can find the element after it has been loaded into DOM.